# using wildcard character [xyz] in cp command

Tags: linux, macos, unix

I want to copy a file named TEST to a bunch of folders named 1/ 2/ ... 9/

I was trying to use

```
cp -v TEST ./[1-9]/
# which gives the result:
TEST '->' ./9/fractionofanions
cp: omitting directory './1'
.
.
cp: omitting directory './8'
```

Can anyone explain why it only copied to folder 9 in the first place, and also any workaround to do what I need? Thanks in advance.

Comment: To format a code block, you can highlight it and use the `{}` editor toolbar button, or `ctl-k`. It is never necessary to place `<br>` tags in code blocks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp` can copy multiple files to a directory, but not files to multiple directories. In this instance, you are attempting to copy `TEST` and directories 1-8 to directory 9/ - see `man cp`
for more information.

However, you can use the following to copy a file into multiple directories, using `find` as a helper:

```
find [1-9] -exec cp file.txt {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can verify in `man cp`, there can only be one target directory specified for `cp`. You can use a loop, though:

```
for target in ./[1-9]/ ; do
    cp -v TEST "$target"
done
```